# Registros duplicados com relacionamento OneToMany

Tags: java, jpa

Tenho um mapeamento da seguinte forma:

```
public class ClasseA {

    public ClasseA(){
        listaClasseB = new ArrayList<ClasseB>;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "xxxx", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ClasseB> listaClasseB;

}

public class ClasseB {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "xxxxxxxxxxx", nullable = false)
    private ClasseA objetoClasseA;

}
```

No método do serviço responsável pelo salvamento:

```
objetoClasseA.getListaClasseB().add(objetoClasseB);
```

E é feito o *persist* ou o *merge* apenas do `objetoClasseA`.

Ao adicionar um `objetoClasseB`, dois registros do mesmo são salvos, mesmo com a lista contendo apenas 1 elemento.

Que motivos poderiam ocasionar a duplicidade de registros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso pode estar ocorrendo por alguns dos motivos abaixo:

1. **Você está utilizando objetos detached em listaObjetosB**. O JPA nem sempre é esperto o suficiente para entender que ele deve criar ou atualizar o **objetoClasseB** contido em **listaObjetoClasseB**. Em outras palavras, instanciar um novo objetoClasseB com todos os atributos preenchidos não garante que o JPA vai saber exatamente o que fazer com ele.
2. **Uso indevido do Cascade** Eu não sei se usou o cascade no mapeamento em ClasseB. Se usou isso pode te dar problema, então sugiro que avalie a necessidade. Eu apenas uso cascade nas entidades principais (que contém a lista).

Caso não seja nenhum dos casos eu solicito que inclua mais detalhes na sua pergunta.

**EDIT**

É muito importante entender bem o **persist** e o **merge**

O **persist** pega a instancia da entidade e a inclui no contexto. A partir deste momento, quaisquer alterações feitas serão refletidas.

O **merge** copia o estado da sua entidade para uma nova instância e inclue esta instância no contexto. Nenhuma alteração subsequente na entidade original será refletida, a não ser que você chame o **merge** novamente.

Na maioria dos casos não existe muito sentido em fazer um **persist** acompanhado de um **merge**, principalmente quando se usa JTA.

Comment: Coloquei a forma como é feito o mapeamento na classe B. Não é feito o uso de cascade. Acredito não se o caso de objetos detached, pois estou testando apenas com a lista vazia, adicionando um único `objetoClasseB`. O que acabei de notar é que ao persistir um `objetoClasseA`, contendo um `objetoClasseB`, o problema não ocorre. Ao fazer o merge na mesma situação, o problema se manifesta. Há algum problema em instanciar a lista no construtor da ClasseA ?

Comment: Então, eu recomendo que você defina os cascades corretamente. Usar os valores padrões pode causar esse tipo de problema.

Comment: O merge do cascade era o que causava problema. Deixei apenas o persist e o delete. O que não entendi é porque o merge salva registros duplicados e o persist não.

Comment: @user1902062 melhorei um pouco minha resposta.